# How to clear the bottom space of ul and li

Tags: php, html, css

I am getting extra space in bottom in li here

Style css of ul and class

```
ul {
  display: table-cell;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

li {
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.Chair {
  background-image: url(Images/blnk.png);
  height: 40px;
}
```

**PHP code**

```
while($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo  '<ul id="sub">';
   if($r['seats'] == null){ 
      echo '<li class="Chair" ></li><ul>';
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: check the height of .Chair

Comment: lower `height` on `.Chair`

Comment: it is ok.i have checked it.bottom space comes from somwhere else

Comment: @Hash .so what to do with the height?

Comment: try using display flex

Comment: @Hash nothing chaged

Comment: `display:block;` on li?

Comment: remove `height: 40px; ` then its working

Comment: i have execute your code and problem is `.Chair` `height:40px` in class

Comment: is ur chair smaller than 40px of height? , if so that is the issue

Comment: and also close the `<ul>` tag properly.. missing `/` in closing `<ul>` tag

Comment: @BilalAhmed you are right.i have solved this  thanks

Comment: @Hash right sir..problem fixed now thanks

Comment: @Bilal Ahmed what is the sence of providing answer in comments?

Comment: @godblessstrawberry i have provide some suggestion in comments..

Comment: @godblessstrawberry and finally i add answer as per my comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per my Comments remove or set `Heights:40px` in `.Chair` class . so this is the complete code

```
 ul {
      display: table-cell;
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }

    li {
      width: 20px;
      float: left;
    }

    .Chair {
      background-image: url(Images/blnk.png);
    }
```

if you want to add height then set `height: 20px`

Comment: The space in the li just because of height of image i set the height of image .Chair 20px ;